# Geometry looks smooth shaded solid mode but becomes flat shaded in material preview or render it

Tags: mesh

The geometry looks as I intended it to look in Solid mode, everything correctly, like this:

[image: Solid mode, correct smooth shading]

But upon entering mat. preview or rendered mode it looks flat shaded, as the mesh is, also for some reason looking reflective as if roughness was at 0 (which is the whole opposite) at least that is only in mat. preview

[image: material preview, seemingly flat shading with artifacts that make it look like a material with no roughness, even though it's at a high value]

I already tried some solutions of similar problems here, like unchecking auto smooth, clearing custom split normals data, joining by distance (deleting vertex doubles), etc..., but none of them worked, apart, some even messed up how it looked in solid.

It doesn't have any modifiers.

Comment: Do you have a normal map by any chance?

Comment: Does the issue remain if you change the material to something simple, like a single Principled BSDF node? If not, then the issue is in the material and we need to see a good screenshot of it to find the problem.